# ValueError: [TypeError("'_cffi_backend.FFI' object is not iterable"), TypeError('vars() argument must have __dict__ attribute')] in FastAPI

Tags: python, google-cloud-firestore, fastapi

I am working with FastAPI and Firestore and I created a very basic endpoint to read all the documents in a collection. However, I get the following error when I run my code and I can't seem to figure out where it's coming from.

`ValueError: [TypeError("'_cffi_backend.FFI' object is not iterable"), TypeError('vars() argument must have __dict__ attribute')]`

The code that I have used is below:

```py
@router.get("/reviews/{review_id}")
def read_review(review_id: str):

    # Get all documents in the Reviews collection
    db = firestore.client()
    reviews_ref = db.collection('Reviews')
    docs = reviews_ref.stream()

    output = {}
    for doc in docs:
        output[doc.id] = doc.to_dict()
    
    return output
```

I am not sure why this error is being generated and I couldn't find anything related to the FastAPI for this error.

Comment: Please include the full traceback, not just the error message. My suspicion is that something somewhere in `output` is a `_cffi_backend.FFI` object, which FastAPI is trying to serialize to JSON. I would print it (or set a breakpoint there in a debugger) to see what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

I just hit this error too. Here's the full error stack as requested above: https://gist.github.com/jhannah/c8113c86f083c6b6645c7d0997d786ee

In my case I was hitting this error because I was returning a firestore reference. Don't do that, it upsets FastAPI. Instead, return a dict. In my case that's from a pydantic class, but pydantic is optional.

```
quiz_result_ref = (
  db.collection("quiz_results")
  .where(filter=FieldFilter("quiz_id", "==", quiz_id))
  .where(filter=FieldFilter("user_id", "==", user_id))
  .limit(1)
  .get()[0]
)
if not quiz_result_ref:
  return None
    
print("quiz_result_ref is a", type(quiz_result_ref))
# quiz_result_ref is a <class 'google.cloud.firestore_v1.base_document.DocumentSnapshot'>
    
# Don't try to return that ref, you'll get your mysterious error:
# return quiz_result_ref
# E      ValueError: [TypeError("'_cffi_backend.FFI' object is not iterable"), TypeError('vars() argument must have __dict__ attribute')]
# ../../../../Library/Python/3.11/lib/python/site-packages/fastapi/encoders.py:238: ValueError

# Instead, return a dict, that error disappears
quiz_result = QuizResult(**quiz_result_ref.to_dict())
return quiz_result
```

I'm new to FastAPI. I imagine an improvement could be made to FastAPI to make it more clear where the mistake was made? Maybe someday I'll take a stab at patching FastAPI.

In your case, check your types in `output`. Maybe you need

```
output[doc.id] = **doc.to_dict()
```